# Помогите исправить код формулы

Tags: c

Ошибка в формуле
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мой код:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define a
#define b
int main()
{
    float u, x[3]={1.3, 1.6, 2.3}, z[4] = {4.51, 4.16, 2.61, 7.28};
    for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
    printf("\n\nz[%d]=%f\n", (l+1), z[l]);
    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
    u = exp(-a[k])*(a[k]+(l*b[l]));
    printf("u=%f\tx[%d]=%f\n", u, (k+1), x[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: жи-, ши- пиши с буквой "и".

Comment: у меня ошыбка в формуле, не так записана, исправьте пожалуйста

Comment: У Вас ошибка в слове "ошыбка". Исправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: `#define a` - вот это что делает?

Comment: я скинул ошыбку, наверное просто не там скобка стоит

Comment: У Вас ошибка в слове "ошыбка".

Comment: теперь исправил

Comment: `#define a` - вот это что делает?

Comment: объявил переменную

Comment: Не надо. Уберите ее. И `b` - тоже.

Comment: Но оно так тоже не работает

Comment: я не понимаю в чем ошибка

Answer (score 0):

Вот правильный код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float u, a[3]={1.3, 1.6, 2.3}, b[4] = {4.51, 4.16, 2.61, 7.28};
    for(int l = 0; l < 4; l++)
    {
    printf("\n\nb[%d]=%f\n", (l+1), b[l]);
    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
    {
    u = exp(-a[k])*(a[k]+(l*b[l]));
    printf("u=%f\ta[%d]=%f\n", u, (k+1), a[k]);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).